# Python best ways to add value based on value in a multi-dimensional dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out the best and fastest way to insert data inside a multidimensional dictionary based on data in the second layer of the dictionary.

My dictionary looks something like this:

```
data = {}
data[12831] = {"sku" : "03921" , "online" = "" ...}
```

The Key 12831 is the ID of the product
The SKU speak for itself
This data dict. contains around 40k elements.

I have an array containing all online SKU no ID

```
online = ["03921","04932",...]
```

So far, the way I would do is
Loop the data dictionary and check one by one if the dictionary sku is in the ONLINE array

```
for key in data:
  if data[key]["sku"] in online:
    data[key]["online"] = 1
```

This method takes 9 seconds to process all 40k products.

Any idea for a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Final code I use.

```
import pandas as pd


online = ["000123","000321",...]

data = {}
data[60011] = {"id":60011, "sku":"000123", "online" : "0"}
data[60012] = {"id":60012, "sku":"000122", "online" : "0"}
data[60013] = {"id":60013, "sku":"000321", "online" : "0"}
...

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')

is_online = df["sku"].isin(online)
df.loc[is_online,'online']='1'

#return to Dictionary
final = df.to_dict('index')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe a `pandas` based appraoch might speed up your process. To validate this I did a quick analysis on the runtime of your and a `pandas` based approach.

I tried replicating your setup by creating a `data` and `online` that contain some random SKU's and keys.

```
from random import randint, seed

seed(42)

data = {}
for i in range(40000):
    data[i]={"sku":randint(0,100000), "online":""}

online = [randint(0,100000) for _ in range(1000)]
```

I timed your approach using `timeit`:

```
def approach1():
    for key in data:
        if data[key]["sku"] in online:
            data[key]["online"] = 1

print(timeit(approach1(), number=10))
>>>> 4.411111836
```

And I did the same for a `pandas` based approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')

def approach2():
    in_online = df.index.isin(online)
    df.loc[in_online,'online']='1'

print(timeit(approach2, number=10))
>>>> 0.020047925999999938
```

As you can see, the `pandas` approach is about 220 times faster than the other one (although the actual difference depends a bit on the size and structure of your data).

Comment: I tried with pandas and I think something is not right. The ID and SKU are not related. I think this look if the SKU is in the ID index. The index is based on the ID not the SKU on line 1 of your approach2()  I may be wrong ;)

Comment: This was a very good lead. I fix this using this :   is_online = df["sku"].isin(online). 0.44 sec to complete and insert in database :) I'm very happy